# Implementing DB Security with Linux

Tags: security, cygwin

I have installed cygwin64 and have been practising linux commands and Shell programming. I am creating a project where I want to restrict file permissions, authenticate user, and execute procedures stored in Database. As I am not very well versed with this, I have been trying different methods. Can I do this in cygwin64? I do not want to download the virtualbox. The prompt remains a $, even when I select run as administrator. Does this mean that my execution of commands would not be affected otherwise. I found on the internet tutorials which say that as the $ prompt does not make one a root user, no security is guaranteed. Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what sort of commands/configuration changes you want to do. "Cyberseurity" is incredibly broad, and we can't help you unless you give us more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

The `chmod` of Cygwin changes ACLs of files, but I have to admit that the mapping between POSIX mode and Windows ACL is not straightforward.

There is no `su` command, no `/etc/passwd`… then all authentication are on the application layer (not the OS or its emulation : Cygwin is not designed as a multiuser OS).

You can find open sources DataBases which support stored procedure. (Mysql, PostgreSQL), but they run natively on Windows : Cygwin is not required.

For an high-level project, perhaps an Apache/PHP/MySQL could do the job.

Note : the usual Unix prompt is `$` for users, `#` for root (administrator). And Cygwin seems to revoke my administrator rights.  `id` doesn’t show me in the Administrators group.

Comment: run as Admin and `id` should show gid Group 544

Comment: I have executed $ chmod 644 in cygwin. Is it ok for webapps/src? What I found is that I have to do penetration testing for webapps, which is available in Kali Linux. My question is, when I am developing a project, how do I ensure authentication(w,r,t, encryption tools like 7-Zip) in cygwin? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You should precise what you mean by authentication. Cygwin is not designed as a multiuser operating system. Then without a `/etc/passwd` it can’t do authentication. You introduce webapps. Precise the context. Do you mean having a web client on Cygwin which authenticate on an external web server ? Then perhaps `curl` Can do the job. And depends of the site you connect (Login/password form, HTTP authrntication…)